# Calculate percentile column from a numeric column

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I am trying to create a calculated column called percentile_Idle_Time(I am trying to calculate percentile for every value). The column is percentile value from idle_time% column.

So, the input data is

```
Total Time   Idle Time    Idle Time %      
 5:10:00      0:14:00       4.6%
 3:09:00      0:20:00       9.49%
   .             .            .
   .             .            .
```

So, I am trying to create a new column called percentile_Idle_Time which is nothing but the percentile position of the Idle Time % value

So, the output data should be like

```
Total Time   Idle Time    Idle Time %    percentile_Idle_Time  
 5:10:00      0:14:00       4.6%             75.4
 3:09:00      0:20:00       9.49%            97.9
   .             .            .               .
   .             .            .               .
```

Note: The numbers are pretty rough(not accurate)
I tried using

```
 proc univariate data=WORK.QUERY_FOR_PEOPLENET_DATA_00_0000 noprint;
 by DriverId;
 var 'Short Idle Time %'n;
 output pctlpre=P_ ;
 run;
```

But its not working. The other challenge is to take percentile score from the % column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it manually then. Sort the data ascending and use the NOBS to get the number of observations. Use *n* to divide by NOBS to get the total value.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by weight;
run;


data want;
  set class Nobs=myobs;

   percentile = _n_ / myobs;
run;
```

NOTE that this does not deal with ties. If you do have ties that need to be dealt with, use PROC RANK instead. I usually do it with a group of 100 and then you'll get the 1 to 100 groups. But its' 96.5 percentile if that's what you're looking for.

```
 proc rank data=sashelp.class out=ranked_class groups=100;
 var weight;
 ranks  weight_percentile;
 run;
```

EDIT: Fixed references in data step and sort to align.

Comment: This, perhaps with `PROC RANK` as first rather than second solution (I like `PROC RANK`). Also congrats on 10k, Reeza, welcome to being able to see deleted posts!

Comment: I also prefer the PROC RANK solution, but OP has 75.4% in their sample so they may want the first option for that reason.